# Prestashop- How to add Amount Due in AdminOrdersController.php

Tags: php, prestashop

My Prestashop version is 1.7.5
I wanted to add the amount due value in the AdminOrdersController. Amount due value can be calculated using ('total_paid_tax_incl'-'total_paid_real')

```
        'total_paid_real' => array(
            'title' => $this->trans('Real Paid', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            'align' => 'text-right',
            'type' => 'price',
            'currency' => true,
            'badge_success' => true,
        ),
```

So I modified it like this

```
        'total_paid_tax_incl'-'total_paid_real' => array(
            'title' => $this->trans('Amount Due', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            'align' => 'text-right',
            'type' => 'price',
            'currency' => true,
            'badge_success' => true,
        ),
```

But It is throwing an error,   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered.
Though both value 'total_paid_tax_incl' & 'total_paid_real' are in decimal(20,6)

Can you guys help me to solve the issue?

Comment: You are trying to subtract two strings here, which obviously won't work. Use the actual variables and not the array keys to calculate the amount.

Comment: Understood, These are not actual variables. So, How can I convert this string to a number for calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom field to the SQL query that generates the order list and then use that field.

In the AdminOrdersController constructor, add

```php
$this->_select .= ' a.total_paid_tax_incl-a.total_paid_real as `due_value`';
```

Right after `$this->_select = '<default query>';`

This will allow you to use the `due_value` variable when defining the columns displayed in the list

```php
'due_value' => array(
             'title' => $this->trans('Amount Due', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
             'align' => 'text-right',
             'type' => 'price',
             'currency' => true,
             'badge_success' => true,
             'havingFilter' => true
         ),
```

Note that I added the havingFilter parameter, because it is not a standard field in the database, but created "on the fly".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added it after the query. But it is throwing an error.
I am wondering what I have done wrong.
https://ibb.co/cFsbHpZ
https://ibb.co/9hdx50m

Comment: My bad. Just add space in the begining `$this->_select .= ' a.total_paid_tax_incl-a.total_paid_real as \'due_value\'';`